# Rails 6 and Highcharts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using Rails 6.0.0.rc1 and hoping to implement the [lazy_high_charts](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts) gem. I installed Highcharts via [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/highcharts) but receiving the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Highcharts
```

Which refers to the following line of code:

```
window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

I checked to see if Highcharts is present via the DOM, which it is. If i add the `<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>` script in my `<head>` tags it loads fine, which is odd. Any help would be appreciated.

**javascript/packs/application.js**

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require('jquery')
require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")

import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import 'bootstrap'
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "app_name",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/actiontext": "^6.0.0-rc1",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0-alpha",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^4.0.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "highcharts": "^7.1.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "trix": "^1.0.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.1"
  }
}
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.3'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0.rc1'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false
gem 'lazy_high_charts'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Can you show your Gemfile?

Comment: Gemfile has been added @Glyoko

Comment: I have found the solution. Adding window.Highcharts = Highcharts; to my application.js worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. Adding:

```
window.Highcharts = Highcharts;
```

to my `application.js` worked. My charts are now showing.

Comment: If you have some time, check this talk about rails and webpack/er https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKOq5_2qj54 specially around minute 17, he shows that case where an old javascript plugin expects something to be on the global scope. He shows the first solution doing something like you did but around minute 23 he shows a better an more modern an "webpackish" solution using the imports-loader loader.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the content of my `application.js` in Rails 6 with webpacker:

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
import HighchartsSolidGauge from 'highcharts/modules/solid-gauge';
import HighchartsExporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';

window.jQuery = jQuery
window.$ = $
window.Highcharts = Highcharts;
```

I've added some extensions as an example.

Answer (score 1):

1. In console `yarn add highcharts`
2. In `app/javascript/packs/application.js` for Rails 6 with webpacket:

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
require("highcharts/modules/data")(Highcharts)
require("highcharts/modules/exporting")(Highcharts)
require("highcharts/modules/offline-exporting")(Highcharts)
require("highcharts/modules/map")(Highcharts)
window.Highcharts = Highcharts;
```